# only returning last value in list with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, html-table

I'm scraping a table and i would like have my tableheaders and tabledata in a list.
When i print it out in my console it looks fine and all the data is there. But when i try to append it and write to excel. the tableheaders show only the last value and duplicates it on each row.

The tabledata column looks great in excel.
It does work when i flip over the tabledata with tableheaders. Wonderings if it's the for loop that's causing it

Can you perhaps see the problem?

```
# Import Library
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

# Open Browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe')

a_Lista = []
# Get the  URL
url = 'write-url-here'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()



nytable = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mca"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody')

headerstitle = nytable.find_elements_by_tag_name("th")
tabledata= nytable.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")

for elementheader in headerstitle:
 print (elementheader.text)
 textelement = elementheader.text
 

for elementdata in tabledata:
    print (elementdata.text)
    textelement2 = elementdata.text

    a_information = {
        'Title for header':textelement,
       'data': textelement2
     
       }

    a_Lista.append(a_information)

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a_Lista)

    df.to_excel (r'location-to-save-file', index = False, header=False)
```

a screenshot from excel

[image]

Comment: how about moving your last two lines of code from the loop, they are overwriting it. out of the loop these two lines: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a_Lista)

    df.to_excel (r'location-to-save-file', index = False, header=False)`

Comment: Thanks for spotting it! How do i take out this lines from the loop? Been trying different things but can't seem to make it work. I almost made it but then the file went crazy duplicating every row and such.

Comment: is the URL in the public domain ? otherwise, post the output of `print (elementdata.text)` and the csv data once you have two lines of code(loc) out from the loop. i.e indentation will be at the same level as `for elementdata in tabledata` which implies that loc got out from the loop.

Comment: Hi, i couldn't really understand what i should have done. Lack in experience here sadly. I did a work around instead.  I made another list on every for loop. then used pd.concat with axis and that pretty much solved it. Might not be as pretty or super functional. But the output was fine. Thanks for taking your time!